# How to create a Jenkins Job with parameters using ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-template

I need a help in Jenkins Job Creation with parameters using Ansible. I have checked many documents but not helping much.

I have checked https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jenkins_job_module.html but not getting what needs to be added in templates/test.xml?

```yaml
- name: Create a jenkins job using basic authentication
  community.general.jenkins_job:
    config: "{{ lookup('file', 'templates/test.xml') }}"
    name: test
    password: admin
    url: http://localhost:8080
    user: admin
```

Comment: See those `config.xml` files all over your jenkins job tree on your server ? That's a pretty good place to start. If you don't have access to the tree directly, getting `http:///<USER>:<API_TOKEN>@your.jenkins.tld/job/JOBNAME/config.xml` with curl or your favorite browser should get you the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple Jenkins job configuration in XML format that you can use as a starting point:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <description>Example Jenkins job with parameters</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>param1</name>
          <description>Example parameter</description>
          <defaultValue>value1</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>echo "Hello, world!"</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a small Docker Jenkins instance locally and create a job: test-job, using the web interface.
With different plugins, my XML templates are different each time, no way to handcraft them by heart.
Then I log in to the Jenkins instance (exec to the container) and copy (cat) the content of:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-job/config.xml
```

into a file called test-job.xml.j2 .
You can also have it from

```
http://localhost:8080/job/test-job/config.xml
```

Then I replace the individual parameters with my "{{ jinja_variables }}" and save the file to the role's templates/ folder.
Then the "jenkins_job" task will have the "config: " attribute like this:

```
config: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/test-job.xml.j2') }}"
```